# Java Mail API, any way to get sure if mail is delivered or not?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee

In my application notification plays an important role, any sensitive activity in the application send notification to the concern person.
These notification are through mails.

Presently in my application i am checking for all the exception during the sendMail() API in no exception in there and mail is send successfully then I mark that mail as Delivered.

But this doesn't means that mail is delivered successfully, sometimes I face many problems like mail bounces back, sometimes email server for the recipient party is not working or any other problem.

So my question is in there any way in JAVA to get sure the mail is delivered successfully? If yes any example or link would be appreciable...

Comment: Research SMTP. All you can know is if the SMTP server you are talking to accepted the mail or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can never know if the mail has been successfully received by  other person.
but by using javamail api you can read the mails of your  "sent mails"  folder to check whether the mail you have sent is in sent mails folder in your email account.
this way you can be sure that at least it has been sent to other user.

i hope this link will help

http://harikrishnan83.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/access-gmail-with-imap-using-java-mail-api/

Folder outbox = store.getFolder(”[Gmail]/Sent Mail”);   can be used to read the sent mail in gmail. 
i hope this will help.